# How do I delete mutiple folders with extension names? (BATCH FILE)

Tags: batch-file

I am currently making a batch file for deleting multiple user downloads. I am stuck on getting a folder with a extension name for example (ccomley.V2).

There is about 172 profiles and I know I could do them all in different command lines but is there a easier way of getting them to delete in one line?

Current line batch file,

```
color 2
del "C:\logs\student_deletion.log"
cls
@echo off
@setlocal

set start=%time%

:: Runs your command
cmd /c %*

set end=%time%
set options="tokens=1-4 delims=:.,"
for /f %options% %%a in ("%start%") do set start_h=%%a&set /a start_m=100%%b %% 100&set /a start_s=100%%c %% 100&set /a start_ms=100%%d %% 100
for /f %options% %%a in ("%end%") do set end_h=%%a&set /a end_m=100%%b %% 100&set /a end_s=100%%c %% 100&set /a end_ms=100%%d %% 100

set /a hours=%end_h%-%start_h%
set /a mins=%end_m%-%start_m%
set /a secs=%end_s%-%start_s%
set /a ms=%end_ms%-%start_ms%
if %ms% lss 0 set /a secs = %secs% - 1 & set /a ms = 100%ms%
if %secs% lss 0 set /a mins = %mins% - 1 & set /a secs = 60%secs%
if %mins% lss 0 set /a hours = %hours% - 1 & set /a mins = 60%mins%
if %hours% lss 0 set /a hours = 24%hours%
if 1%ms% lss 100 set ms=0%ms%

:: Mission accomplished
set /a totalsecs = %hours%*3600 + %mins%*60 + %secs%

cd /d "c:\users"
echo Date: %date% Time: %time% >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
echo. >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log

dir \\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles\ccomley.V2\downloads >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
for /d %%a in (*) do rd /s /q "\\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles\ccomley.V2\downloads" >>nul 2>>&1
@echo Successfully deleted ccomley downloads! (%totalsecs%.%ms%s total) to delete their downloads
echo ccomley took, (%totalsecs%.%ms%s total) to delete their downloads >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
echo. >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log

dir \\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles\anotheraccount.V2\downloads >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
for /d %%a in (*) do rd /s /q "\\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles\anotheraccount.V2\downloads" >>nul 2>>&1
@echo Successfully deleted anotheraccount downloads! (%totalsecs%.%ms%s total) to delete their downloads
echo anotheraccount took, (%totalsecs%.%ms%s total) to delete their downloads >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
echo. >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
```

Hope you can help me! (Side note. I have tried doing *, *.*,)

(Can't show the whole batch file it has private information in there.)

Answer (score 0):

```
dir \\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles\ccomley.V2\downloads >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
for /d %%a in (*) do rd /s /q "\\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles\ccomley.V2\downloads" >>nul 2>>&1
@echo Successfully deleted ccomley downloads! (%totalsecs%.%ms%s total) to delete their downloads
echo ccomley took, (%totalsecs%.%ms%s total) to delete their downloads >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
echo. >> C:\logs\student_deletion.log
```

This block needs to be run repeatedly, with the fixed text `ccomley[.v2]` replaced by a variable.

The easy way is to `call` it as a subroutine, passing the required name as a parameter.

```
:sub
setlocal
set "name=%%~n1"&set "ext=%%~x1"
:: if no ext, abandon ship.
if not defined ext goto :eof
:: otherwise, execute the block with `%~1`, `%name%` and `%ext%' as required.
```

This could be an internal subroutine, or preferably an independent batch, so that you could execute `zap1user fred.bloggs` to delete the user `fred.bloggs`'s files.

Next step is to include the timing in the subroutine. After the `setlocal`, set `start` and after the `for...rd...` set `end`, then do the calculations to generate the report fields. Note that this will **not** affect the `start` and `end` times in the main procedure because of the `setlocal` in the subprocedure.

Last, simply use a `for /d` on the `\\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles` directory to generate the names to be deleted and pass those names to the subroutine via a `call`

```
for /d %%x in ("\\SRV-FILES01\IJ_StudentsW$\Profiles\*") do call zap1user "%%x"
```

and all done!

(well - you could also make your elapsed-time routine into another subsidiary batch which is supplied with two parameters, the start and stop times, and calculates elapsed time. No doubt it will come in useful elsewhere...)

Comment: Thanks, Didn't realize it was gonna be that simple!